# Can I test if my thread looper finished its messages?

Tags: android

I want to test if my Looper finished its work because I want to execute code after all elements of my activity are on screen. I want to trigger an event after Looper finishes its work. Can I do that or is there any another way to execute my code after all elements in the UI appears on screen?

Answer (score 1):

Once you started a `looper` by calling `Looper.loop()` it does *not* exit until you explicitly call `Looper.quit()`.

You can use `Semaphore` to coordinate your code, so you can wait until the Looper finish its work.

1- define a `Semaphore` object in your class and initialize it with `0` permits, e.g.

```
Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(0);
```

2- In the place where you want to `wait` call `semaphore.acquire()`, which will block until a `permit` is available

3- After you finish your looper call `semaphore.release()`, which will add a permit to the semaphore and the other waiting code will continue to run.

Note, that if the looper finished before `semaphore.acquire()` is called; it will continue immediately and will not block

See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782579/waiting-for-soundpool-to-load-before-moving-on-with-application/14782648#14782648), for a code example on using `Semaphore`

Answer (score 0):

You can check the visibility of your elements. If they're true,run your code.... (Hope I understood right.)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: sure this is an answer... it says him a possibility to check his elements.. where is your prob???